# What is the difference between cumulative summation and simple summation?

Tags: python, numerical-methods

Let's say I have a 1-D array which I would integrate it along the z direction. The easiest way, is to replace the integral by a summation times the grid spacing in the z direction, in this case I just get a scalar. But if instead of simple summation I use the cumulative summation I get an array. 
My question what's the difference? and why do I get a array?

Comment: Could you show us your code?

Answer (score 1):

You get an array because this is how [Cummulative Sum](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CumulativeSum.html) is defined.

Answer (score 1):

A cumulative summation is the sum of every element up until a given point.  An example of where this could be useful would be calculating the total number of infections as a function of time from a list of new infections per day.  In code, this could be something like

```
  new_infections_per_day = [0, 1, 5, 10, 22, 5, 1]

  import numpy as np
  total_infections = np.cumsum(new_infections_per_day)
  # Should produce: [0, 1, 6, 16, 38, 43, 44]
```

PS: Infections was the first example that came to mind, given the current world events.

Comment: Thank's for the simple example. I have understood the concept.